# please explain the 3rd line if i take the float it doesnot work why

Tags: python

```
for i in range(1,50,1):
    import math as m
    if int(m.sqrt(i))==float(m.sqrt(i)):
        print(i)
```

it is the program for finding perfect square numbers
can any one explain the `(if int(m.sqrt(i))==float(m.sqrt(i)):)` this line detail i can't understand why it has float

Comment: When would it tell you about `n` if  `int(n)==float(n)`?

Comment: why are you importing `import math as m` 49 times? It is not an issue but why?

Comment: Let's you have a number 10. Then after using `sqrt(10)` it returns `3.1622776601683795`. Using type conversion to `int` will convert to just 3 but if you use `float` will return `3.1622776601683795`. So for your logic `int(m.sqrt(i))==float(m.sqrt(i))` is not true and not perfect square. For the number 16 the condition meets and return perfect number

Answer (score 1):

1 == 1.0 is true

1 == 1.232 is false

when you do `int(m.sqrt(i))==float(m.sqrt(i))` it will return true if value of `float(m.sqrt(i))` doesn't have decimal points and equals to `int(m.sqrt(i))`